# Dexter Library not working in the Android Studio Kotin

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I am using dexter library to get permission of Fine and Course Location if the permission is not given but it's not showing the permissions list when I do Manifest.permission.

I am attaching MainActivity.kt[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee4iP.png), Android Manifest[Android Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDEiI.png), build.gradle[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qayIb.png)

Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.) here after permission. we should get the list of permission but it's not showing in my project.

Comment: Importing wrong Manifest package. Try `import android.Manifest` in MainActivity

Comment: That Solved my Problem. Thanks!